# Display image via php file with content type image Yii

Tags: php, image, header, yii

```
<?php
class TestController extends CController
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
            $filename = "test.jpg";
            $path=Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot.protected.images') . '/';
            $file=$path.$filename;

            if (file_exists($file))
            {
                $img=getimagesize($file);
                header('Content-Type: '.$img['mime']);
                readfile($file);
                exit;
            }
    }
    public function actionDisplayimg()
    {
            echo "<img src='".CController::createUrl('test/')."' />";
    }
}
?>
```

It's not able to display the image neither on test/index or test/displayimg. Any help?

Comment: Elaborate. What is generated? Error? Img read but wrong mime type? File not read? The file exists in the `$file` path though? The `$img` obj is not null and a valid instance of what you expect?

Comment: just a blank page.. No error. But this is confirmed that if (file_exists($file)) is true

Comment: Well. *if* the if branch is executed. However, as you said, the page is blank. If `file_exists` returns false, the if is not executed. I’m not familiar with yii; would it generate something else? Or is actionIndex all that will generate? Then a blank page is expected in the else case.

Comment: on directly accessing the page from browser www.mydomain.com/test/index it is supposed to display the image test.jpg

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. And when did you get blank page?

Comment: instead of exit; always use Yii::app()->end();

Answer (score 3):

I think you must set correct headers and content type for before calling readfile.

```
public function actionIndex()
{
        $filename = "test.jpg";
        $path=Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot.protected.images') . '/';
        $file=$path.$filename;

        if (file_exists($file))
        {

               $request = Yii::app()->getRequest();
               $request->sendFile(basename($file),file_get_contents($file));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

well you may call view and pass it some arguments from action and display them there

for example(NOT TESTED)

```
<?php
class TestController extends CController
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
            $filename = "test.jpg";
            $path=Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot.protected.images') . '/';
            $file=$path.$filename;

            if (file_exists($file))
            {
                $this->render('view',array(
            'filepath'=>$file,
        ));
    }
}
?>
```

and in `view` you can do something

```
echo CHtml::image(filepath, 'image', array('class' => 'banner'));
```

Comment: because some one did not understood it, perhaps some one needs to show his answer......